# Babel ONLY - recursive transpilation of imported files

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, babeljs

Lets say there is a function defined in an external lib which does the following:

```js
export function sum(a, b) {return a + b}
```

And in one of the files in my project, Im making use of this function:

```js
import { sum } from 'specific-lib';

console.log(sum(3 + 4));
```

Is it now possible with babel to recursive transpile my project file, meaning it would also transpile the implementation details of the `sum` function in my output file?

At least I can not find a babel plugin or such, that does something like this...Or do we need a module bundler for this like `webpack`?